# UAC Security Issue when Running Batch Files

Tags: uac, batch

I was having trouble pushing a batch file to a local users machine, when it ran just fine on another person. It turns out I was having the file run as the Current Logged in User.

So the problem is the user is able to run any batch files without being prompted by UAC, they have the highest level of UAC set and they are a local Administrator. Other users with the same level of Access and UAC do get prompted when attempting to run any batch files.

Is there something I am missing here? Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/Set-ExecutionPolicy?view=powershell-5.1)

Try using this commands

> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

This will list the ExecutionPolicy

```
Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

Maybe just maybe this is why, tell me if you see anything

Comment: The question is about batch scripts, the answer is about Powershell.

Comment: Unfortunately, like Multi was saying is for Powershell and not batch scripts.